# How can I create a RSA Encrypter with a String Public Key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have a System that generates a PublicKey, then encrypts a password, then they are both stored in a database.

**PK Generator**

```
public PublicKey GetPK() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            generator.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();

            return pair.getPublic();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

**Password Encryption**

```
public static String EncryptPassword(PublicKey publicKey, String password) {
        try {
            
            Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

            byte[] secretMessageBytes = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(secretMessageBytes);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessageBytes);
        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then, what I try to make Login , I retrieve this Public key, encrypt my login form's password using this Public Key, and it Just don't give me the same encrypted password.

**PuclicKey return**

```
public PublicKey ReturnPK(String keyFromDatabase) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyFromDatabase));
        return kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
    }
```

**Compare Passwords**

```
PublicKey pk = encryption.ReturnHash(GetUsers().getHashCode());
String encryptedPw = encryption.EncryptPassword(pk, pwd);
boolean loginState = encryptedPw.equals(dbPwd);
```

The var loginState always returns false. Can someone help me?

Comment: By generating a Keypair and throwing away the private key you've turned RSA into a password hash, though a very poor password hash at that. Always specify the full transformation string in `Cipher.getInstance()`. Since you didn't you'll get default padding, which in your case is probably PKCS1 ver 1.5 padding and it includes a random component which will be different every time. If you insist on using RSA in this way you'll have to specify NOPADDING in the transformation string, i.e. `Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NOPADDING");` Note: NOPADDING makes it even less secure

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you very Much! I'm still new at Cryptograpy and I'll search about other ways to work with Criptography. I need to make a login system, do you have any idea of what should I search about?

Comment: I recommend argon2 for hashing passwords for login purposes.